# Can't find the value of a UIAStaticText in Appium

Tags: c#, ios, appium, ios-ui-automation

I'm automating some tests for an iPhone. I have a UIAStaticText with the accessibilityid = "total". This test will be updated with the total price after a series of calculations. So, on the final call it could be something like "20.00". I want to find a way through C# and appium's API to find that value.

Answer (score 0):

After calculations, you can just verify the value:

```
Assert.assertTrue("calculationValue","Value doesn't match");
```